# from kivy BoxLayout to ScreenManager using .kv file

Tags: python, screen, kivy, kivy-language

I have an application with 1 screen in BoxLayout (filename qmscreens.py).

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window

class qmHome(BoxLayout):
    pass  

class qmscreensApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)
        Window.size = (500, 500)
        homeWin = qmHome()
        return homeWin

qmscreensApp().run()
```

The examples below have the changes implemented as suggested.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class EditImage(Screen):
    pass

class QmHome(Screen):
    pass

class QManager(ScreenManager):
    elogging = BooleanProperty()

    elogging = True
    # and a lot of other python code here below


class qmscreensApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)
        Window.size = (500, 500)
        homeWin = QManager()
        return homeWin

qmscreensApp().run()
```

and the following qmscreens.kv file:

```
QManager:
    QmHome:
    EditImage:

<QmHome>:
    name: 'home'
    Button:
        on_press: app.root.current = 'edit'
        text: 'to edit screen'
        font_size: 50

<EditImage>:
    name: 'edit'
    Button:
        on_release: app.root.current = 'home'
        text: 'back to the home screen'
        font_size: 50

    CheckBox:
        id: _evlogg_cb
        active: root.elogging
```

The example above gives the error message:

> AttributeError: 'QmHome' object has no attribute 'elogging'

I guess the code line `elogging = BooleanProperty()` should be changed from the `QManager` to the `QmHome` class. But then I get other errors. So I am completely lost. Your help and directions are highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: an instance of `QManager` should be the root widget

Comment: Hi zeeMonkeez, thanks for your answer. So I changed homeWin = gmHome() into homeWin = QManager(). But then I only get a white screen where I was expecting to see the qmHome widget. Is there still a nitty gritty detail missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename all occurrences of the class `qmHome` to `QmHome`. By convention across many different languages, beginning of a class should always start with a capital letter.

Kivy not recognizing the screen named with lowercase seems like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Few fixes. QManager should be the root widget and you missed a <> in the kv file

```
def build(self):
    Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)
    Window.size = (500, 500)
    #homeWin = qmHome()
    return QManager() # <---- :)
```

in the kv file:

```
<QManager>:
    qmHome:
    EditImage:
```

Comment: Hi Yoav, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, this does not work either. Now the first screen is the EditImage screen instead of the qmHome screen (as qmHome is first listen I was expecting this one as the firs screen) and when I click on the button 'back to the home screen' I get the error message: kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: No Screen with name "home"

Comment: Hi, although the examples above work perfectly fine, when adding this "framework" to the existing application I get some other strange behaviour.

 AttributeError: 'QmHome' object has no attribute 'elogging'

in the kv file there is:

           CheckBox:
                    id: _evlogg_cb
                    active: root.elogging
 
and in the .py file there is:

    class QmonosHome(ScreenManager):

        elogging = BooleanProperty()

I have re-edited the code above to make it more clear. Pls can you help as I've lost all directions here.....